# Dual monitor with nvidia drivers on Lubuntu

Tags: nvidia, multi-monitor, xrandr, lubuntu, intel-graphics

After I installed vendor Nvidia drivers, I managed to setup external monitor as I want via */etc/X11/xorg.conf* configuration file:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "SAMSUNG"
    HorizSync       26.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     24.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    Option         "DPI" "96 x 96"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 960M"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "UseEdidDpi" "False"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1680x1050 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

But how do I setup dual screen mode? `nvidia-settings` only detects one monitor, as does `xrandr -q`:

```
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-0 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98    60.05    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95* 
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      74.98    59.89  
   1360x768      60.02  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Also, if it's possible, I would like to have automatic switching between Intel and Nvidia GPU, since I have both (dual GPU). This works on Windows 10 out-of-the-box.